# Python, Pandas: Find first row-index with exact condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

Good evening,

my Dataframe is looking something like this:

```
name    |    age
name_a  |    27
name_b  |    59
name_c  |    41
...
name_z  |    38
```

How can I find the first row - and getting the index - where a certain condition, let's say **"age" >= 40** is fitting?

Thanks for all your help and a great evening to all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on age:

```
df = df.sort_values('age')
```

Then take head(1) after using the condition and sub setting the dataframe based on the condition.

```
df[df['age']>40].head(1)

     name  age
2  name_c   41
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you need to find the first occurrence, you can first create a boolean series from the condition and then use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on the boolean series as [here](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/364575d5.py), which *Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis*:

```
cond = df.age.ge(40)
idx = cond.idxmax() if cond.any() else None
idx
# 1
```